# how to query in php like select field from table $variable?

Tags: php

i tried many q&a in here but still i'm getting a Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

here is my code;

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$teble = $_SESSION['cunn'];
echo $teble;
$sqry = "select * from" .$teble;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($connect,$sqry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

the echo `$teble;` works fine but `$sqry` is my problem
it work if i replace the variable with the actual table name.

Comment: Replace this line =>> if (mysqli_num_rows($connect,$sqry); by if (mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: I think this line is wrong! `$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);` You haven't declare what is **$query**. In your case use **$sqry** in that code instead of $query

Comment: try this : $sqry = "select * from " .$teble;

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqry = "select * from" .$teble;
```

Need to add space between from and table name.

```
$sqry = "select * from " .$teble;
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you missed a space after the "From" try to change this line of code:

```
$sqry = "select * from" .$teble;
```

TO

```
$sqry = " select * from " .$teble;
```